# Is there any sense in such kind of refactoring?

Tags: c#, web-services, refactoring

Given web service method:

```
public void FindSomeEntities(int? Id, string param1, int? param2, ...)
```

Refactored:

```
public void FindSomeEntities(SelectionParameters selectionParameters)

class SelectionParameters
{
    public int? Id;
    public string param1;
    public int? param2
    ...
}
```

Pros:

1. too many parameters in original web service method reduced to the
   only one
2. if there is need to change we won't have to change the
   interface of the method - only the definition of SelectionParameters

Cons:

1. class SelectionParameters hasn't any business value - it's used only
   as helper class and it's used in a single method. As a result we'll
   have many methods with 1 parameters and plenty of one-off classes
2. Actually the interface IS changed, we just push these changes a bit
   deeper.

Comment: I'd rather avoid refactoring like this, it **will** be painful to mantain in the future. When it comes to web services, imho more, simpler (int,string...) parameters is better than less, complex (custom "container" class) ones.

Comment: That's why I asked this question: as for me there's no sense of doing this and I tried to persuade my colleague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refactoring is called [Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).  It is likely to be a good idea if the parameters are naturally related to each other, and especially if they're frequently used together as parameter lists to multiple methods.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is much value in this kind of refactoring because as you say, the number of supporting classes will/could be a pain to maintain and serve no other purpose.

If the parameters have distinct purposes, such as in your example 'ID' then I would think it would be sensible to keep them separate so as to make it easy to identify them and what you want to do with them in the method body.

If however your params are just a collection of values which perform similar/the same functions in the method body, you could look at using the `params` keyword and defining your method like this:

```
public void FindSomeEnteties(params object[] theParameters)
```

It depends whether you want to have to dig through an array to pull out index 0 and treat it as the ID, etc etc, or whether your method simply wants to do the same thing to all the parameters passed.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any reason to believe that the same (sub)set of parameters is shared by other web services, this is reasonable.

Whether you do it not, you have a defacto struct as the argument list anyway.  This observation is realized in our [PARLANSE](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/PARLANSE) programming language, which has always a single argument to function, named '?' (sort of like "self" in OO ).   That argument has a type; it can be a scalar or complex variable (int or string), or it can be struct.  Normally one defines a struct by a struct declaration; in PARLANSE, writing what appears to be multiple arguments implicitly defines a struct.   In those cases where the argument list is passed to a child function, one can simply call that child function on '?' and the entire argument list is passed.